# Setting client service account name in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I am wondering how to set the name for a client service account in Keycloak. At the moment it defaults to 'service-account-{client_id}', I would like to change that.
How can I do it? Is it not possible?
Thanks bunches

Comment: It's not possible. Can you please explain why you want to rename it? Maybe there are other options.

Comment: @sventorben reason is for database auditing, but we can just adjust our code to substitute the username. thank you